Strange Console Warning: Keyboard vs. View Controllers Showdown
I stumbled upon a troubling issue while working on my app's login/password Autofill feature. Every time I tap the "Passwords" button, I get hit with this ominous warning in the console log:
Keyboard cannot present view controllers (attempted to present <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Autofill: 0x10a618e90>)

Now, while the Autofill view controller does eventually show up after I authenticate with FaceID/TouchID, this warning has me worried sick. What's causing this clash between the keyboard and view controllers? And more importantly, is there a way to fix it before it wreaks havoc on my app?
Any thoughts or suggestions on how to proceed with this problem would be appreciated greatly. Thank you all in advance for helping me.
I've meticulously reviewed my code and consulted various resources to resolve the warning message regarding keyboard and view controllers. My expectation was a seamless appearance of the Autofill view controller upon tapping the "Passwords" button, without any warning cluttering up the console log.
